# How to initialise class itself as class Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

How to initialise class as an object with same name

```
>>> class test:
       def name(self,name_):
           self.name = name_
>>> a= test()
>>> a
<__main__.test instance at 0x027036C0>
>>> test
<class __main__.test at 0x0271CDC0>
```

here `a` is an object so I can do `a.name("Hello")`

But what I want to achieve is `test.name("Hello")` without doing something like `test = test()`

Comment: then you need to define name as classmethod. And also it won't support `self.name`  assignment.

Comment: you realize that the first time you call the name method, you are effectively replacing the method with a string right?

Comment: `self` refers the current object. How `self.name` is possible without creating an object?

Comment: @JamesKent I didn't realise that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is don't bother with a "setter" function. Just access the attribute directly. eg.

```
a = test()
a.name = "setting an instance attribute"
test.name = "setting the class attribute"
b = test()
# b has no name yet, so it defaults the to class attribute
assert b.name == "setting the class attribute"
```

If the function is doing something a little more complicated than just setting an attribute then you can make it a `classmethod`. eg.

```
class Test(object):
    # you are using python 2.x -- make sure your classes inherit from object
    # Secondly, it's very good practice to use CamelCase for your class names.
    # Note how the class name is highlighted in cyan in this code snippet.
    @classmethod
    def set_name(cls, name):
        cls.name = name

Test.set_name("hello")
assert Test().name == "hello"
```